# Getting started with Qt + OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl

I want to develop projects based on the 2010 edition of OpenGL's Superbible with Qt. I want to do things like move lights, change their color, activate/deactivate textures, etc. Simple stuff. The Qt documentation I have found so far has been overwhelming. Where can I find a simple tutorial suited to my simple needs?

Answer (score 9):

Have you done any work with OpenGL yet? I know this isn't the answer you want to hear, but I find the newest version of OpenGL to have an extremely steep learning curve. I strongly suggest learning OpenGL 1.x with "direct mode" (glBegin, glEnd calls), then learning about vertex arrays and display lists, and then vertex buffer objects and index buffer objects, and finally shaders.

NeHe has some excellent [tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) to get you started on OpenGL 1.x, and after playing with that for a week or two, it's usually pretty easy to learn about VA's, DL's, and then VBO's. Shaders are pretty hard and actually have their entire own language (GLSL). After you understand all that stuff, you can probably move on to the latest OpenGL stuff a lot easier.

If you're looking to "skip" straight to the latest OpenGL 4.x stuff, [Swiftless tutorials](http://www.swiftless.com/opengltuts/opengl4tuts.html) will get you started, but again, it's an extremely steep learning curve.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've worked before with OpenGL's fixed pipeline functionality. I'm learning shaders now and I wanna move to something beyond Glut for my window managing.

Comment: You're welcome. I've moved the opposite way from you. Something lower than Glut to do my window managing: me. Call me a control freak, but I like to deal with it all myself.

Comment: IMHO there's nothing about Immediate Mode, that makes things easier to comprehend. Vertex Arrays are just as understandable. Heck, I think learning Immediate Mode raises some misconception, that are difficult to shed when it comes to Vertex Arrays. So it is my conviction that Immediate Mode should not be taught.

Comment: The implementation (between VA's and IM) might be just as easy to understand. However, understanding what's going on in the background is a little more complicated. The fact that Immediate mode is passing (to the gpu) each vertex/color/texcoord every single frame, and that VA's are sending a pointer to an array containing all of the data, and VBO's are storing the arrays on the GPU and then telling the GPU which part of the stored data to use. All this is hard to understand from a beginner's perspective, if they're just focused on the code and what's going on in the background.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the Qt OpenGL examples [here?](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-opengl.html)

Maybe you will find something useful in there.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this: http://www.libqglviewer.com/